# how to send mail with nodemailer using SMTP

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, email-templates

i am trying to send an email in my code using smtp as server/host with nodemailer in the node side. but its giving me the unauthorised error while all my credentials are okay.

smtp as server/host with nodemailer in the node side.

```
 var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport( {
                host: "smtp.wgs.wuerth.com",
                port: 25,
                secure: false,
                auth: {
                    user: '*********',
                    pass: '*********',
                },
                tls: {
                    // do not fail on invalid certs
                    rejectUnauthorized: false,
                }
            } );

  transporter.verify( function ( error, success ) {
    if ( error ) {
      console.log('====>'+ error );
    } else {
      console.log( "Server is ready to take our messages" );
    }
  } );
        const email = new Email( {
            message: {
                from: 'aayushi.kumar@wurth-it.in'
            },

            transport: transporter,
            send: true,
        } );

        email.send( {
            message: {
                to: user.email,
                subject: 'forgot password',
            },

            template: templateDir,
            locals: {
                first_name: user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name,
                password: password
            },
        } )
            .then( console.log )
            .catch( console.error );
```

i wanted mails to be sent

but i am getting

```
Error: Invalid login: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
at SMTPConnection._formatError (D:\Projects\Click-2-Order_Mysql\Node\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:605:19)
at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (D:\Projects\Click-2-Order_Mysql\Node\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1340:34)
at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (D:\Projects\Click-2-Order_Mysql\Node\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1298:18)
at SMTPConnection._processResponse (D:\Projects\Click-2-Order_Mysql\Node\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:764:20)
at SMTPConnection._onData (D:\Projects\Click-2-Order_Mysql\Node\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:570:14)
at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (D:\Projects\Click-2-Order_Mysql\Node\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:710:55)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
 code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH LOGIN' }
```

Comment: Have you verified your SMTP configuration with verify() method?

Comment: Yes i have given that i that's the thing that is returning me the error above.I have added that here too